# String.Format is not giving the correct string in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display text in a format in label, but it's displaying an incorrect value.

It's showing the correct value in debug mode. But its displayed wrong on the screen. Ideally, the screen should display total and subtotal as image one.

[image: String value in debug mode]

[image]

**Code to format string**

```
string paymentFormat = "{0,-25} {1,8}\n";
string paymentMode = "Total"; // Or Subtotal
string paymentAmount = "604.00";

string test = string.Format(paymentFormat, paymentMode, paymentAmount);
```

**Update**

```
public class AlertPopupViewItem : ContentView
{
    Label HeaderLabel,MessageLabel;
    public Button OKButton, CancelButton;
    AbsoluteLayout _overlay;
    LoggerService logservice;
    public bool ButtonValue = false;
    StackLayout CancelStackLayout, OKStackLayout;
    string PageSource = string.Empty;

    public AlertPopupViewItem()
    {
        logservice = new LoggerService();
        logservice.WriteData(Constants.DEBUG_LOGGING, "Alert Message Popup ctor.. Start");

        _overlay = new AbsoluteLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black.MultiplyAlpha(0.5),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        };

        Grid mainGrid = new Grid
        {
            HeightRequest = 40,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Padding = 20,
            RowDefinitions =
            {

                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star) },//0 Title
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },//1 Line
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(80, GridUnitType.Star) },//2 Message
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(12, GridUnitType.Star) },//3 OK-Cancel
            }
        };

        HeaderLabel = new Label
        {
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            FontSize = 22,
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            HorizontalTextAlignment= TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions =LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };


        BoxView divider = new BoxView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1,
            Color = Color.Gray,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        };



        MessageLabel = new Label
        {
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None,
            FontSize = 13,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };

        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView()
        {
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical
        };

        scroll.Content = MessageLabel;

        Grid ButtonGrid = new Grid
        {

            HeightRequest = 35,
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition {Width=new GridLength(58,GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition {Width=new GridLength(20,GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition {Width=new GridLength(2,GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition {Width=new GridLength(20,GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
        };


        CancelStackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(-6, -6, -6, -6),
            //VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff9500")
        };

        CancelButton = new Button
        {
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = 15,
            BorderRadius = 0,
            Text = Localizer.Localize("CancelSmall"),
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#01458e"),
            HorizontalOptions =LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BorderColor = Color.Transparent
        };


        CancelButton.Clicked += CancelButtonClicked;

        CancelStackLayout.Children.Add(CancelButton);
        ButtonGrid.Children.Add(CancelStackLayout, 1, 0);

        OKStackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(-6, -6, -6, -6),
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff9500")
        };


        OKButton = new Button
        {
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = 15,
            BorderRadius = 0,
            Text = Localizer.Localize("OK"),
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#01458e"),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BorderColor = Color.Transparent
        };
        OKButton.Clicked += OKButtonClicked;

        OKStackLayout.Children.Add(OKButton);
        ButtonGrid.Children.Add(OKStackLayout, 3, 0);


        mainGrid.Children.Add(HeaderLabel, 0, 0);

        mainGrid.Children.Add(divider, 0, 1);

        mainGrid.Children.Add(scroll, 0, 2);

        mainGrid.Children.Add(ButtonGrid, 0, 3);



        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(mainGrid, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(mainGrid, Findlayoutbounds(new Rectangle(0.20, 0.25, 0.5, 0.50)));


        _overlay.Children.Add(mainGrid);


        Content = _overlay;
        logservice.WriteData(Constants.DEBUG_LOGGING, "Alert Message Popup ctor.. End");
    }

   // ThreadHandle thread = new ThreadHandle();
    private void CancelButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonValue = false;
        this.IsVisible = false;
       // thread.WorkMethod();
    }

    private void OKButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ButtonValue = true;
        if (PageSource == "StarterPage") ;
        //MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ModifyValBooleanForAlert");
        this.IsVisible = false;

       // thread.WorkMethod();
    }

    Rectangle Findlayoutbounds(Rectangle fractionalRect)
    {
        if (fractionalRect.Width - 1 == 0)
            fractionalRect.Width = 0.99;
        if (fractionalRect.Height - 1 == 0)
            fractionalRect.Height = 0.99;
        Rectangle layoutbounds = new Rectangle
        {
            X = fractionalRect.X / (1 - fractionalRect.Width),
            Y = fractionalRect.Y / (1 - fractionalRect.Height),
            Width = fractionalRect.Width,
            Height = fractionalRect.Height
        };

        return layoutbounds;
    }

    public void DisplayAlertPopup(string alertBoxTitle, string alertBoxContent,bool CancelDisplay)
    {
        HeaderLabel.IsVisible = false;
        CancelStackLayout.IsVisible = CancelDisplay;
        CancelButton.IsVisible = CancelDisplay;
        HeaderLabel.Text = alertBoxTitle;
        MessageLabel.Text = alertBoxContent;
        OKButton.Text = Localizer.Localize("OK");
        CancelButton.Text = Localizer.Localize("CancelSmall");
        HeaderLabel.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public void DisplayAlertPopup(string alertBoxTitle, string alertBoxContent, string ButtonText)
    {
        CancelStackLayout.IsVisible = false;
        CancelButton.IsVisible = false;
        HeaderLabel.Text = alertBoxTitle;
        MessageLabel.Text = alertBoxContent;
        OKButton.Text = ButtonText;
    }

    public void DisplayAlertConditionalPopup(string alertBoxTitle, string alertBoxContent, bool CancelDisplay)
    {
        CancelStackLayout.IsVisible = CancelDisplay;
        CancelButton.IsVisible = CancelDisplay;
        HeaderLabel.Text = alertBoxTitle;
        MessageLabel.Text = alertBoxContent;
        this.IsVisible = true;

    }

    public void SetButtonText(string OKText, string CancelText)
    {
        if (OKText != null)
            OKButton.Text = OKText;
        if (CancelText != null)
            CancelButton.Text = CancelText;
    }

}
```

I get the formatted string from some other class and call the `DisplayAlertPopup` method. `MessageLabel` is the label for which I am setting this value.

**Update2:**

As suggested in answer, I have tried the below code to set the font for Android. But its also not displying the text in the required format.

```
MessageLabel = new Label
    {
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None,
        FontSize = 13,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
        TextColor = Color.Black,
        FontFamily = "Droid Sans Mono"
    };
```

Comment: Can you share the xaml page?

Comment: Are talking about the fact both amounts are not aligned?

Comment: @Kzrystof yes, both amounts are not aligned.

Comment: @PaulKaram I have updated the question

Comment: @viveknuna Can't you just change the font to something like Consolas?

Comment: But I’m using the same label for both total and subtotal. Just appending total to subtotal with a newline.

Comment: @Kzrystof what is Consolas? How to use?

Comment: @viveknuna It is the name of a font. Have a look at the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) describing what a monospaced font is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a fixed-width font. There is unfortunately none that is built-in across all platforms, but each platform has its own:

- iOS - Courier New
- Android - Droid Sans Mono
- UWP - Consolas

If no built-in font suits you or you want to have the same experience on all platforms, you can also use custom fonts in Xamarin.Forms. This requires you to find a fixed-width font you like on a service like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). Then you can follow the [tutorial here](https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/) on **Xamarin Help**, that describes how to include the TTF file in each platform and use it from XAML.

The short summary is:

1. Add the font to each platform project with appropriate build action (UWP - Content, iOS - Bundle Resource, Android - Android Asset)
2. Use the `OnPlatform` syntax to set the font (ideally creating a static resource so that it can be reused):

Resource:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="MyFontFamily">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="MyFont.ttf#Open Sans" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/MyFont.ttf#Open Sans" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="MyFont" />
</OnPlatform>
```

And use like this:

```
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontFamily}" />
```

Comment: I am not able to solve my issue, Could you please help?

Comment: Which issue? The solution I have posted does not work?

Comment: I tried Droid Sans Mono for Android. But its displaying the same old wrong format

Comment: One more thing I need to set font in code behind (C# ) not in xaml

Comment: And has the font actually changed (does the ouptut look differently?). Maybe the change was unsuccessful so you are still seeing the default font

Comment: I can see the same text after applying the font. I have updated my question in Update2 (I tried this based on your answer). please let me know I am doing something wrong.